# Run a sql select query in a loop

Tags: mysql

I am monitoring a table in real-time, let's say the table name is user_stats, which keeps a record of users logging into my website and I am monitoring as to how many users have logged in, the query I am using is simple `SELECT * FROM user_stats` 
Now, since the project is live and users are coming logging-in in real time, I am running the same script again and again. Is there a way such that I can tail the query and not run it manually, maybe like an infinite loop? I am using MySQL and running the query in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: so why don't you writet that information to a log file and run tail -f on it? way simpler

Comment: How do I write an SQL SELECT query output into log file? Basically, what I do right now is press the up arrow key and press enter, to run the last query. I want to run that in loop and tail the output. So first point being how to run the statement in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Query,Stored Procedure in a Specific date and time without executing by a user you can do it by using:

```
 Event
```

Mysql Event is a very powerful tool to execute a query or any, "Automatically" by setting up the execution date and time.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about it? Like how to set up an event and time it so that it runs in a loop